# How to use USBee AX logic analyzer under Linux?

Tags: software, linux, logic-analyzer

I've got clone of USBee AX logic analyzer, to play with one and see if I need a device of such type at all. Unfortunately, I haven't found any Linux software that supports one. I have tried Sigrok, but it shows "Failed to configure samplerate" when I try to acquire data. I'm not sure if it is "clone problem" or something. Windows USBee software works ok with my device.

Comment: What's a USBee AX?

Comment: It's popular logic analyzer.

Comment: As a side-note, one of the Sigrok developers who isn't a SE.EE member apparently tracked me down through my google account (which is linked here) and sent `Hey Connor, Saw your answer on Stack Exchange about sigrok. I am one of the sigrok developers (and subscriber to your teardowns on youtube). I don't have a SE account, and don't really want one, but for the love of god could you tell that guy that all he did wrong was selecting a samplerate that's not supported by the firmware? Argh!`

Comment: So it sounds like the issues you had with sigrok were basically just a configuration problem, not that the hardware you have.

Comment: UPD: It looks like Sigrok is in early development stage now, so it would be unfair to judge one. Lastest version seems to be more stable, but still not function as expected.

Comment: UPD2: Last version of Sigrok already works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on which version of the AX you have, there is apparently partial support for that device in [Sigrok](http://sigrok.org/wiki/Main_Page)'s [fx2lafw](http://sigrok.org/wiki/Fx2lafw) package:

[image]

Frankly, I bought a SX clome from china at one point, and the software was so terrible I reprogrammed the EEPROM to make it enumerate as a Saleae Logic-8.
I've purchased a genuine logic-16, so I don't feel that bad about hacking a Chinese clone to emulate the cheaper version. Saleae already has a lot of my money.

Comment: I saw the table, it doesn't work anyway. Probably because it is a clone. I finally found a tutorial how to flash EEPROM without resoldering stuff. Now I'm proud owner of Saleae Logic-8 clone ;) Anyway I consider buying full orginal version in the future. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no. I bet on the wrong horse too when I bought my USBee-SX. The correct device to buy is Saleae's Logic.

Now you can recover from this -- both Saleae and USBee use the same Cypress USB microcontroller, and they're set up exactly the same way as Cypress' development board for the same chip. At least for the digital side you can use Saleae's software if you program the EEPROM on the USBee to match Saleae's USB ID.

The right thing to do is to sell the USBee and buy a device that supports the environment you want to work in. That's what I did with the Logic 16.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. The other reason to buy Saleae Logic is software, which is bit primitive, but "made for people". Fortunately I got clone of USBee, so it was pretty cheap, so I don't have any reason to sell it. And Saleae looks like worth to be bought in original version ;)